# Remix is returning Hydration Error when attempting to map data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, server-side-rendering, remix

When running my Remix project locally, I receive a React hydration error. I notice the HTML from the server doesn't match with the HTML from the client. I'm not sure how to fix the issue. I think it has something to do with using Material UI library. I should be creating a new emotion cache instance on every request. I could potentially not have it setup correctly.

[image]

**Entry.Server.tsx**

```
import type { EntryContext } from '@remix-run/node'
import { RemixServer } from '@remix-run/react'
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'

import { createEmotionCache } from '../css-theme/emotion-cache'
import theme from '../css-theme/theme'

import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline'
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles'
import { CacheProvider } from '@emotion/react'
import createEmotionServer from '@emotion/server/create-instance'

export default function handleRequest(
  request: Request,
  responseStatusCode: number,
  responseHeaders: Headers,
  remixContext: EntryContext
) {
  const cache = createEmotionCache()
  const { extractCriticalToChunks, constructStyleTagsFromChunks } =
    createEmotionServer(cache)

  // Render the component to a string.

  const markup = renderToString(
    <CacheProvider value={cache}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        {/* CssBaseline kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}
        <CssBaseline />
        <RemixServer context={remixContext} url={request.url} />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </CacheProvider>
  )

  // const markup = renderToString(
  //   <RemixServer context={remixContext} url={request.url} />
  // )

  // Grab the CSS from emotion
  const emotionChunks = extractCriticalToChunks(markup)
  const emotionCss = constructStyleTagsFromChunks(emotionChunks)

  const html = markup.replace(
    '<meta name="emotion-insertion-point" content=""/>',
    `<meta name="emotion-insertion-point" content="" />${emotionCss}`
  )

  responseHeaders.set('Content-Type', 'text/html')

  return new Response('<!DOCTYPE html>' + html, {
    headers: responseHeaders,
    status: responseStatusCode,
  })
}
```

**Entry.Client.tsx**

```
import { RemixBrowser } from '@remix-run/react'
import { startTransition, StrictMode } from 'react'
import { hydrateRoot } from 'react-dom/client'

function hydrate() {
  startTransition(() => {
    hydrateRoot(
      document,
      <StrictMode>
        <RemixBrowser />
      </StrictMode>
    )
  })
}

if (window.requestIdleCallback) {
  window.requestIdleCallback(hydrate)
} else {
  // Safari doesn't support requestIdleCallback
  // https://caniuse.com/requestidlecallback
  window.setTimeout(hydrate, 1)
}
```

**Root.tsx**

```
import reactCarouselStyles from 'react-multi-carousel/lib/styles.css'

import type { LinksFunction, MetaFunction } from '@remix-run/node'
import {
  Links,
  LiveReload,
  Meta,
  Outlet,
  Scripts,
  ScrollRestoration,
} from '@remix-run/react'
import { CacheProvider, Theme, ThemeProvider } from '@emotion/react'
import { CssBaseline } from '@mui/material'
import { createEmotionCache } from 'css-theme/emotion-cache'

import theme from '../css-theme/theme'
import { ReactNode } from 'react'

export const meta: MetaFunction = () => ({
  charset: 'utf-8',
  title: 'Ball Hog',
  viewport: 'width=device-width,initial-scale=1',
})

export const links: LinksFunction = () => {
  return [
    {
      rel: 'stylesheet',
      href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap',
    },
    {
      rel: 'stylesheet',
      href: reactCarouselStyles,
    },
  ]
}

const cache = createEmotionCache()

export interface DocumentProps {
  children: ReactNode
  theme: Theme
}

// export default function App() {
//   return (
//     <html lang="en">
//       <head>
//         <Meta />
//         <Links />
//         <meta name="emotion-insertion-point" content="" />
//       </head>
//       <body>
//         <Outlet />
//         <ScrollRestoration />
//         <Scripts />
//         <LiveReload />
//       </body>
//     </html>
//   )
// }

export default function App() {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <Meta />
        <Links />
        <meta name="emotion-insertion-point" content="" />
      </head>
      <CacheProvider value={cache}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <CssBaseline />
          <body data-theme={theme}>
            <Outlet />
            <ScrollRestoration />
            <Scripts />
            <LiveReload />
          </body>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </CacheProvider>
    </html>
  )
}
```

**pages/home/index.tsx**

```
/* eslint-disable react/react-in-jsx-scope -- Unaware of jsxImportSource */
/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */

import { useLoaderData } from '@remix-run/react'
import react, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { HomeLoaderData } from './loader'

import {
  Box,
  Button,
  Card,
  CardActions,
  CardContent,
  Typography,
} from '@mui/material'

import { CardCarousel } from 'src/components/card-carousel'

export function Home() {
  const { liveGames, scheduledGames, metaData } =
    useLoaderData<HomeLoaderData>()

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(liveGames, scheduledGames)
    console.log('meta>>>>>', metaData)
  })

  return (
    <CardCarousel show={4} totalItems={liveGames.length}>
      {liveGames.map((game, index) => (
        <div key={game.id} style={{ paddingRight: '1em' }}>
          <Card sx={{ minWidth: 300 }}>
            <CardContent sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
              <Box>
                <Typography variant="h5" color="text.primary" gutterBottom>
                  {game.home_team.fullName}
                </Typography>
                Home Team Info
              </Box>
              <Box>
                <Typography
                  sx={{ fontSize: 14 }}
                  color="text.secondary"
                  gutterBottom
                >
                  {game.date}
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="h3" color="text.primary" gutterBottom>
                  {game.status}
                </Typography>
                Game Info
              </Box>
              <Box>
                <Typography variant="h5" color="text.primary" gutterBottom>
                  {game.visitor_team.fullName}
                </Typography>
                Away Team Info
              </Box>
            </CardContent>
            <CardActions>
              <Button size="small">View Game</Button>
            </CardActions>
          </Card>
        </div>
      ))}
    </CardCarousel>
  )
}
```

**Access To Code**

[App](https://github.com/rekara-llc/Ball-Hog/tree/dev)

- Run npm install on DEV branch
- Run npm start

The behavior is odd. Sometimes it works. The majority of the time it doesn't.

I tried following this [guide](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/server-rendering/) as I figured the issue stemed from the component library I was attempting to use.

#### Update (11/3/2022)

I looked into a few other documents & examples:

- [Remix and CSS Styles Libraries](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/guides/styling#css-in-js-libraries)
- [Remix + Material/UI Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ut9vkm?file=app%2Froot.tsx)

I'm still getting the same errors, though, but I believe I have a better configuration than before. I pushed the code changes up to my Dev branch. I will leave the example code above untouched for context.

I also notice that when I do a clean npm install, close my current local down and restart the server, everything works fine. When I refresh, that's when I get SSR errors. Does that mean that there is a cache issue? Or that I am not creating a new emotion instance correctly?

Answer (score 1):

It was my Grammarly browser extension that was causing this issue. Didn't know browser extensions could impact SSR.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Remix team are extremely unhelpful in releasing a fix for this (there's a whole lot of finger-pointing that it's a React issue not a Remix one) but the reality is this is only an issue with Remix and not other SSR frameworks.

@OnurGvc has created a really clever workaround to disable injected extension scripts client-side before hydration:

https://gist.github.com/OnurGvnc/31f03f0d5237b78224aa083493fda645

Full code reference below in case the URL changes:

```
function clearBrowserExtensionInjectionsBeforeHydration() {
  document
    .querySelectorAll(
      [
        'html > *:not(body, head)',
        'script[src*="extension://"]',
        'link[href*="extension://"]',
      ].join(', ')
    )
    .forEach((s) => {
      s.parentNode?.removeChild(s)
    })

  const $targets = {
    html: {
      $elm: document.querySelector('html')!,
      allowedAttributes: ['lang', 'dir', 'class'],
    },
    head: {
      $elm: document.querySelector('head')!,
      allowedAttributes: [''],
    },
    body: {
      $elm: document.querySelector('body')!,
      allowedAttributes: ['class'],
    },
  }

  Object.entries($targets).forEach(([targetName, target]) => {
    target.$elm.getAttributeNames().forEach((attr) => {
      if (!target.allowedAttributes.includes(attr)) {
        target.$elm.removeAttribute(attr)
      }
    })
  })
}

function hydrate() {
  clearBrowserExtensionInjectionsBeforeHydration()

  startTransition(() => {
    hydrateRoot(
      document,
      <StrictMode>
        <RemixBrowser />
      </StrictMode>
    )
  })
}
```

This should be added in your `entry.client.tsx`